# C++/CX - How to convert a number stored as String^ to byte?

Tags: string, type-conversion, byte, c++-cx

I have a C++/CX Windows 8 application and I need to do something similar to the following conversion:

```
String^ foo = "32";
byte bar = <the numeric value of foo>
```

How can I convert the number stored within the String^ into the byte type? I am lost without all of the C# magic that I normally use to achieve this!

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Convert to hex then store it in byte array.

Comment: Example? and this must be byte...not byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting into trouble by assuming that C++/CX resembles C#.  That's not the case at all, it is pure C++ with just some language extensions to make dealing with WinRT types easier.  This is not appropriate use of the Platform::String type, it is **not** a general purpose string class.  That's already covered by the standard C++ library.  The class was intentionally crippled to discourage the usage you have in mind.  This [MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699879.aspx) explains it well:

> Use the Platform::String Class when you pass strings back and forth to methods in Windows Runtime classes, or when you are interacting with other Windows Runtime components across the application binary interface (ABI) boundary. The Platform::String Class provides methods for several common string operations, but it's not designed to be a full-featured string class. In your C++ module, use standard C++ string types such as wstring for any significant text processing, and then convert the final result to Platform::String^ before you pass it to or from a public interface. It's easy and efficient to convert between wstring or wchar_t* and Platform::String.

So the appropriate code ought to resemble:

```
#include <string>
...
    std::wstring foo(L"32");
    auto bar = static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stol(foo));
```

Comment: Thanks Hans - I appreciate the response. I think you are assuming that I am the one creating this String^ (as a result of my condensed example to state the problem more clearly). Actually, this value is passed to me by a WinRT API as a String^, and unfortunately I have another API which needs to receive the value as a byte. There is nothing that I can do about this in my code, hence the need for conversion :) Sorry if the condensed example confused things - I am quite familiar with CX/String^ and only use it when necessary. I will convert it to wstring and go from there - thanks!